# Binding to a monad that is inside a data structure in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to define bind that only affects a part of a data structure?

For example, say we have a mock Computation data type that has a Name and a Result.

```
type Name          = String
data Error         = TimeOut | NotEnoughMemory | DivByZero
type Result a      = Either Error a
data Computation a = Computation Name (Result a)
```

Since the computation could fail but we might still be interested in its name, it can't be part of Result and must be part of Computation. On the other hand it would be also convenient to bind and validate results of Computations directly like you would do with a regular Either type. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Suppose you were to bind a computation, which `Name` should the output `Computation` have? What name should a `Computation` produced with `return` have?

Comment: `Computation` just looks like it binds a name to the result of some anonymous computation, rather than representing any computation itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you probably can't define any useful `instance Monad Computation`, since you cannot define `pure :: a -> Computation a` from the `Applicative` class (which is a superclass of `Monad`); how would you instantiate the `Name` given just a value of type `a`?

It is a `Functor` though (and you can derive it automatically). With more context there might be a different abstraction that would be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

*TW [monad transformers](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html)*

I think you may want

```
type Computation = ExceptT Error (Writer Name)

-- in familiar types:
-- Computation a ⋍ (Either Error a, Name)
```

Notice that `Name` has to be a `Monoid` now.  That makes sense, since

```
liftA2 (+) comp1 comp2
```

, which adds the results of two sub-computations, needs to also have a name.  What the `Writer` component does is concatenates (with the monoid's `<>` -- so not necessarily just string concatenation) the names of the two sub-computations.  Perhaps you would use, for example:

```
newtype Name = Name [String]
    deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
```

You would probably also want a way to define the name of some computation:

```
name :: String -> Computation a -> Computation a
name n = mapExceptT (censor (const (Name [n])))
```

For example:

```
two :: Computation Int
two = name "two" $ pure 2

someComp :: Computation Int
someComp = name "two plus two" $ liftA2 (+) two two
```